# Why is it impossible to make a Markup TextInput in kivy?

Tags: kivy, markup, textinput

So i am trying like for months using different techniques to make a markup textinput. However their are a million issues that arises. However if we would see `TextInput.py` we can see that the textinput uses a `label` for displaying text. so I tried dding a `markup = True` to that label. However I see no good result. So why is it that kivy textinput have no markup. and is it possible to add a markup.

Answer (score 0):

TextInput uses labels, but it doesn't inherit the Label class. Even though you set `markup = True`, nothing happens because TextInput doesn't have the attribute. The kivy document says

```
The TextInput widget provides a box for editable plain text.
```

Answer (score 0):

> So why is it that kivy textinput have no markup.

Ultimately, because it's hard and nobody has both wanted to and had time to implement that feature.

> and is it possible to add a markup.

It is certainly technically possible, but you'd need to read the TextInput source and work out how to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `TextInput` to create a markup capable `TextInput` by importing `MarkupLabel` as `Label` like this:

```
from kivy.core.text.markup import MarkupLabel as Label
from kivy.cache import Cache
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture

Cache_get = Cache.get
Cache_append = Cache.append


class MarkupTextInput(TextInput):
    def _create_line_label(self, text, hint=False):
        # Copy this method from TextInput with no changes
```

The `_create_line_label()` method creates a `Label` and uses the `Texture` from that `Label` in the `TextInput`. Normally `kivy.core.text.Label` is used, but the above mentioned `import` results in `kivy.core.text.markup.MarkupLabel` being used instead.

That will give you a `MarkupTextInput` where you can type in markups (like`[b]` and `[/b]`). It is still not complete because the cursor position will be incorrect. When you type in `[b]`, those three characters suddenly disappear, but the cursor position won't back up. Fixing that is the hard part. Maybe someone can figure that part.